# eliminating variable from a pair of trig relations

Tags: trigonometry

If $$\operatorname{cosec} A - \sin A=m$$

and $$  \sec A - \cos A=n,$$

please show how to eliminate $A$; I have tried that and it came:

$$\sin A \cdot \cos A = m\cdot n$$

Comment: Next time please try to choose a descriptive title for your post. Do not title it "help me pls".

Answer (score 1):

We have $\cos^2A=m\sin A\  \ \ \ (1), \sin^2A=n\cos A\ \ \ \ (2)$

$(1)$ can be rewritten as  $\sin^2A+m\sin A-1=0\ \ \ \ (3)$

$(1)+(2)\implies m\sin A+n\cos A=1\implies(1-m\sin A)^2=(n\cos A)^2$

$\implies (m^2+n^2)\sin^2A-2m\sin A+1-n^2=0 \ \ \ \ (4)$

Solve $(3),(4)$ for $\sin A,\sin^2A$ and use $\sin^2A=(\sin A)^2$

Answer (score 0):

$$ 1/s - s = m, 1/c - c = n  $$

$$ 2\, s = - m \pm \sqrt{m^2 +4} ,  2\, c = - n \pm \sqrt{n^2 +4}  $$

$$  ( - m \pm \sqrt{m^2 +4} )^2 + ( - n \pm \sqrt{n^2 +4} )^2  = 4.  $$

Answer (score 0):

We have $mn=\sin A\cos A\ \ \ \ (1), \csc A - \sin A=m\iff\cos^2A=m\sin A\ \ \ \ (2)$

Putting the value of $\sin A$ in $(1),mn=\dfrac{\cos^2A}m\cdot \cos A\iff\cos^3A=m^2n$

and from $(2),(m\sin A)^3=(\cos^2A)^3=(m^2n)^2\implies\sin^3A=mn^2$

Can you take it from here?